# Linq to retrieve only the item's where the list contains NONE OF THESE language Id's

Tags: c#, linq

I need to retrieve the searchRecords which contains the translation as Dog but not in the specified language.

Attached minimal code mimic the scenario.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
public class translation{
        public string text;
        public int languageId;
    }
    public class searchData{
    public string name;
        public List<translation> translations;
    }
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
     List<searchData> searchRecords = new List<searchData>(){
      new searchData { name = "A", translations =  new List<translation> { new translation(){text = "Dog", languageId = 1 }, new translation(){text = "Dog", languageId = 2 }, new translation(){text = "Dog", languageId = 3 }, new translation(){text = "Cat", languageId = 4 }} },
      new searchData { name = "B",translations =  new List<translation> { new translation(){text = "Dog", languageId = 1 }, new translation(){text = "Cat", languageId = 2 }, new translation(){text = "Cat", languageId = 3 }, new translation(){text = "Cat", languageId = 4 }} },
      new searchData { name = "C",translations =  new List<translation> { new translation(){text = "Horse", languageId = 1 }, new translation(){text = "Horse", languageId = 2 }, new translation(){text = "Horse", languageId = 3 }, new translation(){text = "Horse", languageId = 4 }} }
     };
     List<int> langIds = new List<int> { 3, 4};

     // Need to return the strings which contain Dog but not in translations where Language Id is 3 and 4
     var res = searchRecords.Where(data => data.translations.Count(t => t.text.Contains("Dog") && langIds.Contains(t.languageId)) == 0);
     // Basically returns B

     foreach(var i in res)
     {
       Console.WriteLine(i.name);
     }
  }
}
```

It should return me the second searchRecord. I'm not able to think of how this can be achieved.

Comment: So the first `searchData` should not be included since it also contains *dog* with `languageId == 3`, even though it has one item that is a match?

Comment: @smoksnes Yes it should not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for Any that contains "Dog" as `text` and than exclude those in Any contains "Dog" with prohibited `langIds`:

```
var res = searchRecords.Where(data => data.translations.Any(t => t.text == "Dog") &&
                                      !data.translations.Any(t => t.text == "Dog" &&
                                                       langIds.Contains(t.languageId)));
```

Some notes:

- Classes in C# are with first letter Uppercase, by convention
- So are public fields, but I suggest you to use properties instead
- Do not use `Count` when you just want to test if there is at least one, use `Any`

---

You can do it in one-pass with two nested `foreach`s:

```
var res = new List<searchData>();
foreach (var data in searchRecords)
{
    var toBeAdded = false;

    foreach (var transl in data.translations)
    {
        if (transl.text == "Dog")
        {
            if (langIds.Contains(transl.languageId))
            {
                toBeAdded = false;
                break;
            }
            toBeAdded = true;
        }
    }
    
    if (toBeAdded)
    {
        res.Add(data);
    }
}
```

It's much less elegant, but certainly faster.
You definitely must evaluate how many data you have to process.

You can also write that in a `LINQ`-ish way, but you can't take advantage of the `break` on the first prohibited translation occurrence:

```
res = searchRecords.Where(data =>
    {
        var toBeAdded = false;
        data.translations.ForEach(transl => toBeAdded = transl.text == "Dog" ? !langIds.Contains(transl.languageId) : toBeAdded);
        return toBeAdded;
    });
```

Comment: It works fine, but doesn't it run through the data set twice?

Comment: Yeah, although not twice actually, since the first condition exclude some cases (in your example, the "C" searchData). Unfortunately here you have two different requirements ("contains the word Dog", "not contains the word Dog in some languages") and those have to be tested separately. I currently don't see a way to do it in one-pass, at least with LINQ. It's probably easier with a for loop since you can set some variables that survives loops.

Comment: I added a foreach one-pass version

Comment: The thing is I'm fetching data from database, rather than a list, mentioned above

Comment: Records are anyway fetched in memory so you shouldn't notify big differences, unless you are processing millions of them

Comment: Actually they are in millions

Comment: So go for the `foreach` way, it's the fastest for sure.

Comment: Or you may consider a SQL approach.